# Product of values of the derivative of a polynomial at its roots

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $K$ be a field and $f(x) \in K[x]$ be irreducible and separable, with distinct roots $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$. In my notes for my algebraic number theory class, I see the equality
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f'(\alpha_i) = \prod_{j \neq i} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)
$$
where $f'(x)$ denotes the formal derivative. Where does this equality come from?

Comment: Hint: $f(x)$ factors as $(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$ in the algebraic closure $\bar{K}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As potla wrote,
$f(x)
=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-a_i)
$.

To get $f'(x)$,
use
$\ln f(x)
=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x-a_i)
$
so
$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{x-a_i}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=f(x)\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{x-a_i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{f(x)}{x-a_i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1, j\ne i}^n(x-a_i)\\
\end{array}
$

Note:
If you don't like the use of $\ln$,
you can prove this by induction on $n$
using the product rule.

Therefore
$f'(a_k)
=\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1, j\ne i}^n(a_k-a_j)
= \prod_{j=1, j\ne k}^n(a_k-a_j)
$
since all the other terms
(with $k \ne i$) have
$a_k-a_k$.

Therefore
$\prod_{k=1}^n f'(a_k)
= \prod_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1, j\ne k}^n(a_k-a_j)
$.